Drag and Drop component where both drag and drop both horizonatally and vertically in Angular
Problem statement
I am trying to develop a interface which is dynamic length 2 dimensional metrics (M x N) where N is of different length and can grow and shrink. Think the interface like a checker box with different values in those boxes. However checkbox is constant length but I am talking about a growing dynamic length rows and columns.
Component
Refer following components for reference which I need to merge together with any place drag and drop.

https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#cdk-drag-drop-sorting
https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#cdk-drag-drop-horizontal-sorting

I am new to Angular and this is something I am unable to resolve. Please help or guide. If you can suggest any custom library then also I am good.
So far I could able to achieve the run-time matrix creation using drag and drop. I am able to manage horizontal moves only at a time. The problem is that project also demands vertical drop down as well also group drag and drop.

Since Angular CDK v18.1.0, you can use cdkDropListOrientation="mixed" for two-dimensional drag and drop. For a detailed explanation and a demo, see their docs.

Thanks. Only problem that we observe how to know from where to where we should move. It is not a random move. As I said, they should be part of mXn matrix and they should be in a perfect row column combination.
